# Android: TextWatcher.onTextChanged fires when binding to EditText

Tags: android, textwatcher

When I set a `TextWatcher` to a `EditText` like so:

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

Interface methods `onTextChanged`, `afterTextChanged` and `beforeTextChanged` are fired, no matter if the `EditText` contains text or not.

I assumed that these methods are called only after a text change after binding. Can I prevent this behaviour? Have I made a logical error that is resulting in this behaviour?

Thanks

#### Edit:

I `setText()` before `addTextChangedListener`.

call stack:

```
DalvikVM[localhost:8600]    
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended)   
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    EditText(TextView).sendOnTextChanged(CharSequence, int, int, int) line: 7875    
    EditText(TextView).setText(CharSequence, TextView$BufferType, boolean, int) line: 3488  
    EditText(TextView).setText(CharSequence, TextView$BufferType) line: 3341    
    EditText.setText(CharSequence, TextView$BufferType) line: 90    
    EditText(TextView).setText(CharSequence) line: 3316 
    EditText(TextView).onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable) line: 3216    
    EditText(View).dispatchRestoreInstanceState(SparseArray) line: 10079    
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those methods should not fire when you just call `addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher)`. Likely you are just calling `setText()` or otherwise modifying the text programatically.

---

This is the source code of `android.widget.TextView.addTextChangedListener`:

```
public void addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher) {
    if (mListeners == null) {
        mListeners = new ArrayList<TextWatcher>();
    }
    mListeners.add(watcher);
}
```

Comment: I setText() before addTextChangedListener. Is this problematic?

Comment: Before? It shouldn't be... if you remove that line does it still get called? It's just that there must be a reason for the `TextWatcher` to be fired. If you can't find why, you can set a boolean flag after you're done setting up the UI and while it's false initially just return from the `TextWatcher`'s methods.

Perhaps you're restoring state or something after `addTextChangedListener`?

Comment: i only setTxt in my onCreate method. if i dont set it nothing happens! I have a ViewPager. The issue happens only if I scroll back to a previously loaded page. I set the TextWatcher to null onDestroyView and create a new one if the Fragment reloads. I checked that the old one gets deleted before onCreateView.

Comment: The problem is here - setting the `TextWatcher` to null won't remove it from the `EditText`! It's already attached to it internally - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270484/how-to-remove-all-listeners-added-with-addtextchangedlistener). You can thus either implement this custom `EditText` or just use the a flag to disregard the event. For example:

1) set flag to return from `TextWatcher`, 2) call `setText()` as needed, 3) unset the flag

Comment: the problem is that editText's onRestoreInstanceState calls the setText. See my call stack. Why I dont know.

Comment: problem is that fragments does not get deleted (memory leak that im aware of). he reuses the previous view and its elements when scrolling back and sets the text

Comment: Yup, exactly. Once you add a `TextChangedListener` it will stay that way, and `TextWatcher` will internally call `setText()`. Usually this isn't a problem because the views are destroyed but your case with the view pager is special... you need a flag as such.

Comment: How should I set this flag? I cannot distinguish if setText comes from user interaction or from onRestoreInstanceState.

Comment: Set the flag to allow the `TextWatcher` to work within your `onPostCreate()`.