# AutoCompleteTextView : AfterTextChange and OnItemClick working together

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, autocompletetextview

I have added AutoCompleteTextView in my app. In which I have coded on both methods i.e. afterTextChange() if a person writes complete word and do not click on suggestion and OnItemClickListener() if a user clicks on sugesstion but the problem is that these both methods are working together. If I click on suggestions using onItemClick then afterTextChange( ) also works and my code runs two times. What to do to prevent both methods not run same time.

**OnAfterTextChange() Code**

```
 actvShop_name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                   actvShop_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtShop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //do nothing
            if ((actvShop_name.getText().length() != 0) && actvShop_name.getText().length() >= 3) {
                modelShopDetailsArrayList = databaseHelper.getShopDetail(actvShop_name.getText().toString(), language);

                Log.e("TAG", "onKeyDown:Add " + modelShopDetailsArrayList.size() + " " + actvShop_name.getText().toString() + language);

                if (modelShopDetailsArrayList.size() != 0) {

                    HashMap<String, String> shopDetails = session.getSelectedShopDetail();

                    Log.e("TAG", "onItemClick: " + shopDetails.get("shop_name_nl") + "  ");

                    if (shop_name != null) {

                        if (shop_name == actvShop_name.getText().toString()) {

                            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(actvShop_name.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

                            fillShopDetails(actvShop_name.getText().toString());

                        } else {


                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                            alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.delete_cart);
                            alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
                                    databaseHelper.deleteCart();

                                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                                            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(actvShop_name.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

                                    fillShopDetails(actvShop_name.getText().toString());


                                }
                            });
                            alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.no
                                    , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                            alertDialog.show();


                        }

                    } else {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                                Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(actvShop_name.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

                        fillShopDetails(actvShop_name.getText().toString());
                    }
```

**OnItemClickListener() Code**

```
 actvShop_name.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


          //  actvShop_name.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

            shop_name_entered = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            actvShop_name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txtShop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtShop.setText(shop_name_entered);


            HashMap<String, String> shopDetails = session.getSelectedShopDetail();

            Log.e("TAG", "onItemClick: " + shopDetails.get("shop_name_nl") + "  " + shop_name_entered);

            if (shop_name != null) {

                if (shop_name.equals(shop_name_entered)) {

                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(actvShop_name.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

                    fillShopDetails(shop_name_entered);

                } else {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.delete_cart);
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
                            databaseHelper.deleteCart();

                            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(actvShop_name.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

                            fillShopDetails(shop_name_entered);


                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.no
                            , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }

            } else {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                        Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(actvShop_name.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

                fillShopDetails(shop_name_entered);
            }


        }
    });


    actvShop_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            actvShop_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtShop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    txtShop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            actvShop_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtShop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Dialog opened two times as both methods are running together.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same problem, which you are facing now.

As we are using the `addTextChangedListener`than it will fire when any change will happen to your `EditText` either from the typing or setting the text programmatically (like selecting a value from the list and then set on Editext)

You can use the two approaches for it.

1. Disable the `addTextChangedListener` listener from the AutoCompleteTextView. For this click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14834042/3946958)
2. Play with view visibility (which I have used successfully). For this, you need to create a new view (you can create **TextView**) on your `AutoCompleteTextView` and set the visibility of the view to **GONE** by default than we will play the view visibility programmatically like inside the `addTextChangedListener` use below code

Code:

```
  @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //do nothing
    YOUR_AUTO_COMPLTE_TEXTVIEW.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    YOUR_TEXTVIEW.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
```

And inside the `setOnItemClickListener` again we need to play view visibility as follow and set the set text on the new `Textview` check below:-

```
actvShop_name.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                YOUR_AUTO_COMPLTE_TEXTVIEW.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                YOUR_TEXTVIEW.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
}
```

And apply click on the YOUR_AUTO_COMPLTE_TEXTVIEW and the YOUR_TEXTVIEW to set the view visibility like below

```
YOUR_AUTO_COMPLTE_TEXTVIEW.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                YOUR_AUTO_COMPLTE_TEXTVIEW.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                YOUR_TEXTVIEW.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        YOUR_TEXTVIEW.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                YOUR_AUTO_COMPLTE_TEXTVIEW.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                YOUR_TEXTVIEW.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried 1. approch but not working still same problem.

Comment: You can try second one , which i have used...Do you have any problem on it

Comment: I added but same problem now

Comment: How it can be...Have u created the 2 views like `AutoTextView` and `TextView` and set the `visibility` as i have mentioned in the answer..Because same thing i have tried for and it working now perfectly

Comment: Yes, Did the same. Do i need to share code with you.

Comment: You can edit your question .. i willl check from there

Comment: One more thing , which u need to add on my above solution.. I am editing my answer

Comment: @mishti I have edited the answer..Please check it once..Apply click listener on the AutoTexvie and Texview check above solution

Comment: @mishti You have applied the `onItemclik` and `addTextChangedListener` listeners on the same view..What is the use of the  `addTextChangedListener` on the `AutoCompleteTextview`

Comment: Where I do not find. Please elaborate

Comment: What is the use of the `addTextChangedListener ` on the `AutoCompleteTextview` ??

Comment: actvShop_name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { this one?

Comment: I need to check when typing fininsh in autotext. to add aftertextchange I used it?

Comment: Refer this link for it http://blog.hackerkernel.com/2015/12/30/autocompleteedittext-with-dynamic-data-from-json/

Comment: I do not understand what you want to say

Comment: Click on the above link which i have mentioned on ealier comment

Comment: I checked but not understand

Comment: On this **link** [click here](http://blog.hackerkernel.com/2015/12/30/autocompleteedittext-with-dynamic-data-from-json/) , they have used the `ArrayAdapter` with **Filterable** interface..And from this you do not need any `addTextChangedListener` on your `AutoTextview` ,Try to undserand that code on the link..Your probelm will resolve easily..