# animate changing of text size like android L calculator

Tags: android, animation, calculator, typeface, text-size

In android L calculator app when you try too add more than ten digits 
Text size changes with a cool animation. so Text/Font size goes smaller and you can fit more digits 
How can I do that ?

**[UPDATE]**
[As shown in this Video](http://cld.persiangig.com/dl/q5BLw/3ORWDn5g7B/movie-0.mov)

Comment: can u show any example?

Comment: yes ... I uploaded a Video

Answer (score 1):

Try these properties. Should be anyone from this.

```
    android:translationX=""
    android:translationY=""
    android:transformPivotX=""
    android:transformPivotY=""
    android:scaleX=""
    android:scaleY=""
```

Comment: I don't see how that relates to letters of an EditText

Comment: thanks but I still can't apply it ... could you take a look at the video ?
because the size and scale of EditText/TextView remains the same after all

Comment: I have Android 5.0 with me. But the text size changes after the zoomin/out animation.

Comment: exactly ... What i meant was how to animate changing of the text/font size not the whole TextView Size

Answer (score 1):

for the Animation use this example :

[TextView Animation Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677250/animation-of-textviews-text-size)

do it in the Callback onTextChanged which occurs when you Type a char in the View

Hope it helps.

also you can use the same Animation to EditText but use this Example for this : 
[EditText addTextChangeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064952/android-edittext-and-addtextchangedlistener)